# User Trajectory Creation with Python

Tags: python, sorting, gps, gis

I'm in need of some assistance creating trajectories in python. I have a CSV with user_ids, timestamp, latitude, and longitude. I would like to create a 5th column in my file (or write to new file all together) containing the trajectory of each user_id, which requires grouping the coordinates by their user, and sorting (ascending) by the timestamp. I was able to accomplish in PostGIS, but the results are geometries and what I need are strings of coordinates. I have tried using collections and itertools, as well as Pandas, to group and sort, but I'm struggling.

For reference, here is a few lines of my data:

```
user_id, timestamp, latitude, longitude
478134225, 3/12/2017 9:04, 38.8940974, -77.0276216
478103585, 3/12/2017 9:04, 38.882584, -77.1124701
478073193, 3/12/2017 9:07, 39.00027849, -77.09480086
476194185, 3/12/2017 9:14, 38.8048355, -77.0469214
476162349, 3/12/2017 9:16, 38.8940974, -77.0276216
478073193, 3/12/2017 9:05, 38.8549, -76.8752
477899275, 3/12/2017 9:08, 38.90181532, -77.03733586
477452890, 3/12/2017 9:08, 38.96117237, -76.95561893
478073193, 3/12/2017 9:05, 38.7188716, -77.1542684
```

As you can see, there are users with multiple entries, so I need to group by them and order the coordinates by time. E.g. something similar to below

```
478073193 (38.8549,-76.8752)(38.7188716,-77.1542684)(39.00027849,-77.09480086)
```

I have well over 150k points, so doing by hand like I did above isn't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. It uses the popular pandas package and numpy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# First we import the data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=', ')

# Now get a list of unique user_id values
uniqueIds = np.unique(data['user_id'].values)

# Now just get the ordered (by timestamp) coordinates for each user_id
output = [[id,data.loc[data['user_id']==id].sort_values(by='timestamp')[['latitude','longitude']].values.tolist()] for id in uniqueIds]
```

The **output** is a list with each element of the form [id, list_of_paired_coordinates], e.g.:

```
[[476162349, [[38.8940974, -77.02762159999999]]],
 [478073193, [[38.8549, -76.8752],
              [38.7188716, -77.1542684],
              [39.00027849, -77.09480086]]],
 [478103585, [[38.882584, -77.11247009999998]]],
 [478134225, [[38.8940974, -77.02762159999999]]]]
```

## Edit

If you'd like to save the output in JSON format you could do something like:

```
import json

# Now turn our array into a dict {id:coordinates}
outputDict = {}
for i in output:
    outputDict[i[0]]=i[1]

with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(outputDict, f, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',',':'))
```

Depending on how you'd like the output file formatted you may need to modify the structure of **outputDict** a little bit (let me know if this is the case). Right now the JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "476162349":[
        [
            38.8940974,
            -77.02762159999999
        ]
    ],
    "476194185":[
        [
            38.804835499999996,
            -77.0469214
        ]
    ....
```

## Edit 2

If you want to format the output JSON file you can add labels to the values stored in the dict:

```
outputDict = {}
for i in output:
    coords={}
    latList=[]
    longList=[]
    for j in i[1]:
    latList.append(j[0])
    longList.append(j[1])
    coords["latitude"]=latList
    coords["longitude"]=longList
    outputDict[i[0]]=coords
```

The output JSON file would look this this:

```
{
    "476162349":{
        "latitude":[
            38.8940974
        ],
        "longitude":[
            -77.02762159999999
        ]
    },
    "476194185":{
        "latitude":[
            38.804835499999996
        ],
        "longitude":[
            -77.0469214
        ]
    }
        ....
```

Comment: As a side note: you may get a warning about the parser for reading the csv file. You can use the command data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delimiter=', ', engine='python') if you'd rather not see the message (code will still work).

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly! Side question, might you know a way to format or write this to json?

Comment: Have a look at the edit @AndrewR. Also - if the answer did the trick you can mark it as correct :-)

Comment: I'm getting a TypeError: 'separators' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: That's strange, it works fine for me? You can safely remove the 'separators' keyword anyway.

Comment: Taking it out worked, thanks! You mentioned formatting the structure of outputDict, how do you mean?

Comment: Robbie, how might I edit the dict so the keys are user_id, and lat/long or x/y for the coordinates?

Comment: In the dict the keys are the user_id values - you can only have one set of keys, so what do you mean by user_id *and* lat/long?

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding the JSON scheme. I wanted to edit the dict so when reading the JSON file it will read something like: "user_id":xxxxxx "coordinates": "latitude":[1234], "longitude":[5678] - assuming this still allows the file to be in correct JSON format

Comment: Okay I think I understand, see if the most recent edit does what you are after.

Comment: Currently away from my script, so I can't test, but based on the output, that is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Robbie, just curious, when creating the trajectories using what you provided, is is possible to split into smaller line segments based on the user_id, e.g., [478073193, [[38.8549, -76.8752],[38.7188716, -77.1542684],[39.00027849, -77.09480086]]] into: user_id [position1,position2], [position2,position3]. The question might sound weird to ask, but I've clustered my points (nodes) using DBSCAN, and I'm trying to aggregate my trajectories as movements between the nodes/positions using their cluster labels.

Comment: Hi Andrew, do you mean in the output JSON file?

Comment: Either as in the string or JSON file. I opened up a new question last night and received a few solutions so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302821/python-splitting-trajectories-into-steps