# Python: splitting trajectories into steps

Tags: python, pandas, graph, networkx

I have trajectories created from moves between clusters such as these:

```
user_id,trajectory
11011,[[[86], [110], [110]]
2139671,[[89], [125]]
3945641,[[36], [73], [110], [110]]
10024312,[[123], [27], [97], [97], [97], [110]]
14270422,[[0], [110], [174]]
14283758,[[110], [184]]
14317445,[[50], [88]]
14331818,[[0], [22], [36], [131], [131]]
14334591,[[107], [19]]
14373703,[[35], [97], [97], [97], [17], [58]]
```

I would like to split the trajectories with multiple moves into individual segments, but I am unsure how.

**Example:**

```
14373703,[[35], [97], [97], [97], [17], [58]]
```

**into**

```
14373703,[[35,97], [97,97], [97,17], [17,58]]
```

The purpose is to then use these as edges in NetworkX to analyse them as a graph and identify dense movements (edges) between the individual clusters (nodes).

This is the code I've used to create the trajectories initially:

```
# Import Data
data = pd.read_csv('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_cluster_outputs.csv', delimiter=',', engine='python')
#print len(data),"rows"

# Create Data Fame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['user_id','timestamp','latitude','longitude','cluster_labels'])

# Filter Data Frame by count of user_id
filtered = df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: x['user_id'].count()>1)
#filtered.to_csv('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_final_filtered.csv', index=False, header=True)

# Get a list of unique user_id values
uniqueIds = np.unique(filtered['user_id'].values)

# Get the ordered (by timestamp) coordinates for each user_id
output = [[id,filtered.loc[filtered['user_id']==id].sort_values(by='timestamp')[['cluster_labels']].values.tolist()] for id in uniqueIds]

# Save outputs as csv
outputs = pd.DataFrame(output)
#print outputs
headers = ['user_id','trajectory']
outputs.to_csv('G:\Programming Projects\GGS 681\dmv_tweets_20170309_20170314_cluster_moves.csv', index=False, header=headers)
```

If splitting this way is possible, can it be completed during the processing, as opposed to after the fact? I'd like to perform it while creating, to eliminate any postprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `apply` and custom function with `zip`, for output list of lists in necessary list comprehension:

**Notice**:

*[`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.count.html) function return all no `NaN` values, if filtering by `length` without NaN better is `len`.*

```
#filtering and sorting     
filtered = df.groupby('user_id').filter(lambda x: len(x['user_id'])>1)
filtered = filtered.sort_values(by='timestamp')

f = lambda x: [list(a) for a in zip(x[:-1], x[1:])]
df2 = filtered.groupby('user_id')['cluster_labels'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df2)
    user_id                                     cluster_labels
0     11011                            [[86, 110], [110, 110]]
1   2139671                                        [[89, 125]]
2   3945641                  [[36, 73], [73, 110], [110, 110]]
3  10024312  [[123, 27], [27, 97], [97, 97], [97, 97], [97,...
4  14270422                             [[0, 110], [110, 174]]
5  14283758                                       [[110, 184]]
6  14373703  [[35, 97], [97, 97], [97, 97], [97, 17], [17, ...
```

Similar solution, filtering is last step by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
filtered = filtered.sort_values(by='timestamp')

f = lambda x: [list(a) for a in zip(x[:-1], x[1:])]
df2 = filtered.groupby('user_id')['cluster_labels'].apply(f).reset_index()
df2 = df2[df2['cluster_labels'].str.len() > 0]
print (df2)
    user_id                                     cluster_labels
1     11011                            [[86, 110], [110, 110]]
2   2139671                                        [[89, 125]]
3   3945641                  [[36, 73], [73, 110], [110, 110]]
4  10024312  [[123, 27], [27, 97], [97, 97], [97, 97], [97,...
5  14270422                             [[0, 110], [110, 174]]
6  14283758                                       [[110, 184]]
7  14373703  [[35, 97], [97, 97], [97, 97], [97, 17], [17, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution uses the magic of pandas' `.apply()` function. I believe this should work (I tested this on your sample data). Notice that I also added an extra data points on the end for the case when there is only a single move, and when there is no move.

```
# Python3.5
import pandas as pd 


# Sample data from post
ids = [11011,2139671,3945641,10024312,14270422,14283758,14317445,14331818,14334591,14373703,10000,100001]
traj = [[[86], [110], [110]],[[89], [125]],[[36], [73], [110], [110]],[[123], [27], [97], [97], [97], [110]],[[0], [110], [174]],[[110], [184]],[[50], [88]],[[0], [22], [36], [131], [131]],[[107], [19]],[[35], [97], [97], [97], [17], [58]],[10],[]]

# Sample frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_ids':ids, 'trajectory':traj})

def f(x):
    # Creates edges given list of moves
    if len(x) <= 1: return x
    s = [x[i]+x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
    return s

df['edges'] = df['trajectory'].apply(lambda x: f(x))
```

Output:

```
print(df['edges'])

                                                edges  
0                             [[86, 110], [110, 110]]  
1                                         [[89, 125]]  
2                   [[36, 73], [73, 110], [110, 110]]  
3   [[123, 27], [27, 97], [97, 97], [97, 97], [97,...  
4                              [[0, 110], [110, 174]]  
5                                        [[110, 184]]  
6                                          [[50, 88]]  
7          [[0, 22], [22, 36], [36, 131], [131, 131]]  
8                                         [[107, 19]]  
9   [[35, 97], [97, 97], [97, 97], [97, 17], [17, ...  
10                                               [10]  
11                                                 []
```

As far as where you can put this in your pipeline - just put it right after you get your `trajectory` column (whether that's after you load the data, or after you do whatever filtering you require).

Comment: This works perfectly on the data subset I provided, however, when I feed it my full data set as a csv I get a lot of empty moves and the moves that are present are not split properly. For example, `[[[, [8, 86, 6], ],, , ,  [, [1, 11, 10, 0], ]...`. This is also present when writing to csv. I see you're using Python 3.5, I'm on 2.7, could that be causing an issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you `zip` your trajectory with itself offset by one you get your desired result.

**Code:**

```
for id, traj in data.items():
    print(id, list([i[0], j[0]] for i, j in zip(traj[:-1], traj[1:])))
```

**Test Data:**

```
data = {
    11011: [[86], [110], [110]],
    2139671: [[89], [125]],
    3945641: [[36], [73], [110], [110]],
    10024312: [[123], [27], [97], [97], [97], [110]],
    14270422: [[0], [110], [174]],
    14283758: [[110], [184]],
    14373703: [[35], [97], [97], [97], [17], [58]],
}
```

**Results:**

```
11011 [[86, 110], [110, 110]]
14373703 [[35, 97], [97, 97], [97, 97], [97, 17], [17, 58]]
3945641 [[36, 73], [73, 110], [110, 110]]
14283758 [[110, 184]]
14270422 [[0, 110], [110, 174]]
2139671 [[89, 125]]
10024312 [[123, 27], [27, 97], [97, 97], [97, 97], [97, 110]]
```

Comment: I understand how this works using the data subset I provided, I performed it and worked perfectly, but how might I alter to read from a file? I have a csv with a few thousand trajectories I would like to perform this on.

Comment: @AndrewR.  One major point of Stackoverflow is to get a body of answerable questions and their answers.  This allows people to search and quickly find information.  I answered the way did because I could.  The problem presented at the top of your question was answerable, and thus got three interesting answers.  The other questions were more vague. This question has been answered and accepted, please create another question (they are free after all), paying attention to creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.